# Android N - Application does not support multi-window

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I am trying to test the new feature multi-window with my application and every time I try to make my application fit in half of the screen I get a toast saying that my application does not support that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My application activities only supports the `portrait` orientation, that is why I am getting this toast.

> If the app declares a fixed orientation, you should attempt to put the
>   app in multi-window mode. Verify that when you do so, the app remains
>   in full-screen mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:resizeableActivity
```

Set this attribute in your manifest's `<activity>` or `<application>` element to enable or disable multi-window display:

```
android:resizeableActivity=["true" | "false"]
```